# Extracting the text file data in python based

Tags: python, string, list, file, split

I have a vhdl code file and a data list. In order to automate the report i want to only extract the output ports from the vhdl text file. It is a huge source file but i am only interested in the PORT declarartion to find whether the ports that are in my data list are declared as input or output in the vhdl file.

A part of the input file is below:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

LIBRARY blk_mem;
USE blk_mem.blk_mem;

ENTITY blk_mem IS
  PORT (
    clk1 : IN STD_LOGIC;
    en1 : IN STD_LOGIC;
    we1 : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(0 DOWNTO 0);
    addr1 : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 DOWNTO 0);
    din1 : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
    dout1 : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0)
  );
END blk_mem;
```

My data list is

```
clk1
en1
clk1
en1
dout1
```

I have to check if the list content i.e clk1,en1... is in the vhdl file and check if its input or output..if it is output..then print that whole line from the vhdl code.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

something like this - the code generates a python dict with the required info

```
ports = {'clk1','en1','dout1'} # TODO add more ports if needed
data = {}
with open('vhdl.txt') as f:
  lines = [l.strip() for l in f.readlines()]
  for l in lines:
    parts = l.split(':')
    if len(parts) == 2:
      port = parts[0].strip()
      if port in ports:
        data[port] = parts[1].strip()
print(data)
```

Comment: @balderman...There's a little concern over this...I have pasted just the part of the input file i am interested in...the entire file has many instances where clk : is used...however..i am interested only in the lines mentioned in PORT()

Comment: @balderman..i have updated the question....my data list is a list of ports which are present in the vhdl file...I am interested only in the lines that are present inside the PORT function in the vhdl file...this function has the port details..If the port from the list is declared as output in the file..then i have to print the line from that file for that particular port